# Flutter - Google Play OpenSSL 1.1.1h vulnerability warning

Tags: android, openssl, google-play, flutter-native

While publishing a new release of my app to the Google Playstore, I suddenly got a warning about my app using vulnerable OpenSSL versions (specifically 1.1.1h).

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-arm, locale en-NL)
    • Flutter version 3.3.7 on channel stable at /Users/_________/Documents/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision e99c9c7cd9 (7 days ago), 2022-11-01 16:59:00 -0700
    • Engine revision 857bd6b74c
    • Dart version 2.18.4
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/_________/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14B47b
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-arm64 • Android 12 (API 31) (emulator)
    • iPhone 13 pro (mobile)      • 893E06BD-1977-495E-A6E8-A388953D0C13 • ios           • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-1 (simulator)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

I went through the packages that were added since the previous release. These were:
uni_links, informers, open_store, android_id, package_info_plus, internet_connection_checker, analyzer.

I tried checking which android dependencies use 'OpenSSL' from the unzipped apk, along with checking it in the Flutter SDK itself. This was done using `unzip -p app-develop-debug.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"` and some other scripts that I got from other Stackoverflow issues.
I only got `flutter_web_sdk` that was using it from the SDK, and `libsqlcipher.so` binary from the unzipped APK.

I then tried to build the openssl using the newer sources, but it was too convoluted, and just did not work directly with android side of things.

I tried to add
`com.bryanherbst.openssl-checker:openssl-checker:1.0.0` and `org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:7.3.0` to my buildscript, hoping that it would point me to the actual package using it (not a binary/header or something). But it did not seem to trigger the checking workflow when running from Flutter.

I tried to upgrade my gradle plugin to 7.4, ext.kotlin_version to '1.7.20', and ndkVersion to '25.1.8937393' (so everything to the latest without breaking the app). I also updated all the dependency-plugins used, to their latest version in android. But upon compiling and checking the APK, references to OpenSSL 1.1.1h were still there.

I do not understand how to get rid of this. How could I find the packages that are using it (I do have quite some outdated packages declared in my pubspec.yaml, but cannot be easily upgraded).
And what can I check next, to replace openssl 1.1.1h usage with the next secure version? Or is it a deeper error that would still remain unsolved?

Comment: Any update for this question?

Comment: Seems like noone knows about a conrete solution.

Comment: Did you find the solution?